# simple json response with cakephp

Tags: ajax, json, cakephp

I trying to pass some json to a controller in cakePHP 2.5 and returning it again just to make sure it is all going through fine.

However I getting no response content back. Just a 200 success. From reading the docs I am under the impression that if I pass some json then the responseHandler will the return json as the response.

Not sure what I am missing.

Data being passed

```
var neworderSer = $(this).sortable("serialize");
```

which gives

```
item[]=4&item[]=3&item[]=6&item[]=5&item[]=7
```

appController.php

```
public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar', 
    'Search.Prg', 
    'Session', 
    'Auth',
    'Session',
    'RequestHandler'
);
```

index.ctp

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/btstadmin/pages/reorder",
        type: "post",
        dataType:"json",
        data: neworderSer,
        success: function(feedback) {
            notify('Reordered pages');
        },
        error: function(e) {
            notify('Reordered pages failed', {
                status: 'error'
            });
        }
    });
```

PagesController.php

```
public function reorder() {

    $this->request->onlyAllow('ajax');
    $data = $this->request->data;
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->set('_serialize', 'data');

}
```

UPDATE:
I have now added the following to the routes.php

```
    Router::parseExtensions('json', 'xml');
```

and I have updated my controller to

```
    $data = $this->request->data;

    $this->set("status", "OK");
    $this->set("message", "You are good");
    $this->set("content", $data);
    $this->set("_serialize", array("status", "message", "content"));
```

All now works perfectly.

Comment: So you are using (or you want to) the [**JSON view**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html), right?

Comment: Yes I want to use the JSON view, from reading the docs does cakephp not select the appropriate view needed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### A proper `Accept` header or an extension should to be supplied

In order for the request handler to be able to pick the correct view, you need to either send the appropriate `Accept` header (`application/json`), or supply an extension, in your case `.json`. And in order for extensions to be recognized at all, extension parsing needs to be enabled.

See [**http://book.cakephp.org/...views.html#enabling-data-views-in-your-application**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#enabling-data-views-in-your-application)

### The view only serializes view vars

The JSON view only auto-serializes view variables, and from the code you are showing it doesn't look like you'd ever set a view variable named `data`.

See [**http://book.cakephp.org/...views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key)

### The view needs to be rendered

You shouldn't disable [**auto rendering**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::render) unless you have a good reason, and in your case also finally invoke `Controller:render()` manually. Currently your action will not even try to render anything at all.

### CakeRequest::onlyAllow() is for HTTP methods

`CakeRequest::onlyAllow()` (which btw is [**deprecated as of CakePHP 2.5**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#CakeRequest::onlyAllow)) is for specifying the allowed `HTTP` methods, ie `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, etc. While using any of the available detectors like for example `ajax` will work, you probably shouldn't rely on it.

### Long story short

Your `reorder()` method should look more like this:

```
public function reorder() {
    if(!$this->request->is('ajax')) {
        throw new BadRequestException();
    }
    $this->set('data', $this->request->data);
    $this->set('_serialize', 'data');
}
```

And finally, in case you don't want/can't use the `Accept` header, you need to append the `.json` extension to the URL of the AJAX request:

```
url: "/btstadmin/pages/reorder.json"
```

and consequently enable extension parsing in your `routes.php` like:

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

### ps

See **[Cakephp REST API remove the necessity of .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202294/cakephp-rest-api-remove-the-necessity-of-format)** for ways to use the JSON view without using extensions.

Comment: Thank you. I had reorder.json but I broke the app. I was missing Router::parseExtensions('json', 'xml'); now it all works

Answer (score 0):

Output your json data

```
public function reorder() {

$this->request->onlyAllow('ajax');
$data = $this->request->data;
$this->autoRender = false;
$this->set('_serialize', 'data');
echo json_encode($data);

}
```

Comment: Yes I have just tried this and I now get the output. So the data is there. Does $this->set('_serialize', 'data'); not do the same?